# Mongoose connection from Namecheap server to MongoLab gives error: MongoError: no primary found in replicaset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab, namecheap

I have NodeJs app on the Namecheap server. Mongo db is hosted on MongoLab. When trying to connect to the database with mongoose I'm getting the following error: Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
{ MongoError: no primary found in replicaset

MONGO_URI=mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-0dwia.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-0dwia.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-0dwia.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority

Mongo: 4.0.12
Node: v9.11.2

I am able to connect to the database with the same url from my local machine.
Does someone know what could be the issue?

Comment: You have to ask NameCheap to open the outgoing port for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a connection issue with namecheap servers.
I also suggest looking into heroku instead of namecheap servers.